# convert passport usage from mongoose to sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am building an app that requires authentication during login and for that I have used passport(passport-local). The app does not run for the login part and the last option available after removing all syntax errors is that the way in which I am using passport(as given in their docs) is for mongoose while I am using sequelize. Can someone please tell how to rectify my passport.js file so that it works fine for sequelize as well?
(using mysql through sequelize; database is already populated)
here is my passport.js file

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const Users = require('./db').Users

module.exports = function (passport) {
  console.log("passport is working");

  passport.serializeUser(function (users, done) {
    console.log("Serialize");
    done(null, users.id)
  })

  function findById(id, fn) {
    User.findOne(id).exec(function (err, user) {

      if (err) {
        return fn(null, null);
      } else {
        return fn(null, user);
      }
    });
  }

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log("DeSerialize");
    findById(id, function (err, user) {
      console.log(user);
      done(err, user);
    });
  })

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
      Users.findOne({ where: { username: username } },
        function (err, users) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!users) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
          }
          if (!users.validPassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
          }
          return done(null, users);
        });
    }
  ));
}
```

and here is my db.js file

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const db = new Sequelize(
  'mydb',
  'myuser',
  'mypass',
  {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    pool: {
      max: 8,
      min: 0,
      aquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    },
  }
);

const Users = db.define('users', {
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  }

})


db.sync().then(() => console.log("Database is ready"))

exports = module.exports = {
  db,
  Users
}
```

also,as a side note,can I do a res.send after post request using passport.authenticate?

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'),
function(req, res) {
    res.send({
        url:'/profile',
        username:req.body.username
    });
  });
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

`findById` has been replaced by `findByPk` method in Sequelize 4.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to change the functions where you fetch your user. This:
`function findById(id, fn)`

Should be something like:

```
function findById(id, fn) {
    User.findById(id).then((user) {
      return fn(null, user);
    });
  }
```

And you also need to change this a bit:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
      Users.findOne({ where: { username: username } })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: '' });
          }

          // validate your password**
          return done(null, user);
        });
    }
  ));
```

If you want to use a function like `user.validatePassword()` you will need to define an instance method (check sequelize docs) or [here](https://medium.com/@benjaminconant/defining-instance-methods-on-sequelize-js-models-dea36f478950)

.

Comment: Tried still same result

Comment: neither serialize nor deserialize is printed in console.

Comment: in the terminal it just converts the input parameters into a sql query string but does not provide the output result. the query is correct as when i hard coded into my sql database, i get the correct result. it is only not happening when i do it from sequelize.

Comment: try removing this variable `module.exports = function (passport) {` you don't need to pass it to the function. You already defined it above

Comment: www.github.com/leoking-crey/webdev_project/tree/debug

Comment: this is my source code; upon removing module.exports = func(passport) it is showing an error of "unknown authentication strategy 'local'"